# Seaborn jointplot joint density level / color scale adjustment

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jointplot

I can show you better than I can explain:

I use seaborn to draw a jointplot of two time series, but I would like to change the scale of the density so that more of the joint distributions would be visible.

This is what comes out with:

```
g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", ratio=5, size=7, space=0)
```

Pic 1: seaborn jointplot of two time series:
[image]

But when I superimpose the observations on top of the jointplot I can see that there are plenty of observations outside the colored areas. I use g.plot_joint to superimpose the scatterplot:

```
g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, c="k", s=10, linewidth=1, marker="+")
```

Pic 2: jointplot with scatterplot superimposed
[image]

Is there a way to adjust the jointplot in some way to show a larger area of the distribution? I would like to see some coloring even in areas with less dense joint distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `n_levels` keyword. The default is `n_levels=10`. It is not well documented, but I found it digging in the source.

```
g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", ratio=5, size=7, space=0, n_levels=100)
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you Rob! I tried to find something like that from the documents but could not find it.

Comment: It still works for me. Of course it only works when `kind='kde'`, since the keyword is passed to the underlying kdeplot.